# Passing CCSprite from old scene to new scene in a transition, in Cocos2d

Tags: sprite, cocos2d-x, fadein, transition

I have a sprite (a Heads Up Display) which is visible on the old scene, and I use CCTransitionFade to transition from old scene to new scene, but I would like this sprite to stay on top of both the new and old scene during the transition.

Currently before the transition starts I remove the sprite from the old scene, and add it to new scene. This way the sprite immediately disappears when the old scene fades away, and appears on the new scene. The problem, that it should be visible on the old scene while it is fading away, and should be visible on the new scene as it is fading in.

If it's not clear, here is some code:

int oldScene:

```
HUDLayer *hud = this->getHUD();
hud->retain();
hud->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
newScene->addChild(hud);
hud->release();
 CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(CCTransitionFade::newScene);
```

My only workaround so far is to make an exact copy of hud, and add it to the newScene. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please don't use the [cocos2d-iphone] engine tag for questions concerning only the [cocos2d-x] engine.

Comment: Making a copy is the only way, either by recreating the HUD with the same values or capturing the node into a render texture.